# why mongo is fetching results even after deleting the collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine

using pymongo i have deleted a particular collection. when i query the database using mongoengine 
x.objects.get(y="something") is still showing up with the deleted result.

anyone please help me with this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you delete the collection: `collection.remove()` or `collection.drop()`?

Comment: I was using pymongo. I used db.drop_collection(coll)

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [drop](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.drop) method:

```
from pymongo import Connection
connection = Connection('localhost', 27017) #Connect to mongodb

print(connection.database_names())  #Return a list of db, equal to: > show dbs

db = connection['testdb1']          #equal to: > use testdb1
print(db.collection_names())        #Return a list of collections in 'testdb1'
print("posts" in db.collection_names())     #Check if collection "posts" 
                                            #  exists in db (testdb1)

collection = db['coll']
print(collection.count() == 0)    #Check if collection named 'coll' is empty

collection.drop()                 #Delete (drop) collection named 'coll' from db
```

Comment: I got my mistake. I was deleting in a cloned database instead of original one. Its working fine now. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @andros1337 No worries :)